# Purchasing item without registering as a user

Tags: meteor, payment, stripe-payments, user-experience

I have this site where visitors can pay for certain digital goods, after which they'll be presented with a download link. These downloads links last for a week before they die and become useless

I want to allow users to purchase items without having to create an account first, but just by supplying the payment details and email. I figured I could send the download link to their email once paid, but this is kind of problematic if they accidentally specific an incorrect email when paying.

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to check out the [cart](https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/cart) package.

Answer (score 0):

I've made such a purchase on a site called WrapBootstrap (https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/flatboard-angularjs-admin-frontend-WB0G434G7). It integrates with PayPal in that they are navigated to PayPal, pay, and when they return, PayPal notified the site the payment was successful and then WrapBootstrap displays the download link.

I liked how seamless it was but what I found was if I ever wanted to download an item again, I didn't have a personal record of it (either in email or account). One drawback from a non-account perspective. Check it out and let me know if that answers your question.